# How can I draw bidirectional arrows with smartdiagram package?

Tags: arrows, smartdiagram

I'm trying to do a diagram with bidirectional arrows, but I don't know how to do this on `smartdiagram` package. I also need to erase the last feedback arrow. Anyone can help me?

### My Code

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Banco de Baterias,
    Conversor CC-CC, Inversor CC-CA, Rede}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want

```
\smartdiagramset{arrow style=<->, back arrow disabled}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{arrow style=<->, back arrow disabled}
\smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{Banco de Baterias, Conversor CC-CC, Inversor CC-CA, Rede}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I want